# How to use pipeline and ColumnTransformer in python?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to run a Linear Regression in python sklearn on [this](https://www.kaggle.com/kumarajarshi/life-expectancy-who) dataset. I want to impute the NaN values, and in three specific columns I want to replace zeros with NaN so that I can impute those values too. Note: there are other columns with zeros that do not need to be imputed.

For the imputation I am trying to use [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html#columntransformer-for-heterogeneous-data) and then use pipeline to run the linear regression. I used [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-columntransformer-to-combine-data-processing-steps-af383f7d5260) article for reference. However, I am getting an error: `ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames`

Can someone verify my process, and let me know if I am doing something wrong?

```
df[['percentage_expenditure', 'income_composition_of_resources', 'schooling']] = df[['percentage_expenditure', 'income_composition_of_resources', 'schooling']].replace(0, nan)

# Split dataframe into input and output variables.
x = df.iloc[:,df.columns != 'life_expectancy']
y = df.iloc[:, 3] # life_expectancy is the output column (variable)

# Split into train and test datasets.
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=40)
# print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)

# Build transformers OnHotEncoder and SimpleImputer for categorical and numeric columns respectively.
categorical_features = ['country', 'year', 'status']

numerical_features = ['adult_mortality', 'alcohol', 'percentage_expenditure', 
                      'hepatitis_b', 'bmi', 'polio', 
                      'total_expenditure', 'diphtheria', 'gdp', 
                      'population', 'thinness_1-19_years', 
                      'income_composition_of_resources', 
                      'income_composition_of_resources', 'schooling']

transformers = [
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), categorical_features),
    ('impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), numerical_features)
]

column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers, remainder='passthrough')
X_train_transformed = column_transformer.fit_transform(X_train)
column_transformer.named_transformers_['onehot'].get_feature_names()
# X_train_transformed

lr = LinearRegression()
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessing', column_transformer),
    ('lr', lr)
])
# edit this part to X_train instead of X_train_transformed
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Still have an error. See below
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-f4e9a8bf0d7a> in <module>
     72     ('lr', lr)
     73 ])
---> 74 pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
     75 
     76 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    333             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
    334                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 335                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    336 
    337         return self

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    503 
    504         n_jobs_ = self.n_jobs
--> 505         X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'],
    506                                    y_numeric=True, multi_output=True)
    507 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    430                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    431             else:
--> 432                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    433             out = X, y
    434 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    793         raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
    794 
--> 795     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
    796                     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
    797                     dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     70                           FutureWarning)
     71         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 72         return f(**kwargs)
     73     return inner_f
     74 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    573     if sp.issparse(array):
    574         _ensure_no_complex_data(array)
--> 575         array = _ensure_sparse_format(array, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
    576                                       dtype=dtype, copy=copy,
    577                                       force_all_finite=force_all_finite,

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _ensure_sparse_format(spmatrix, accept_sparse, dtype, copy, force_all_finite, accept_large_sparse)
    382                           % spmatrix.format, stacklevel=2)
    383         else:
--> 384             _assert_all_finite(spmatrix.data,
    385                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
    386 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
     94                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     95             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
---> 96             raise ValueError(
     97                     msg_err.format
     98                     (type_err,

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Comment: You want the pipeline to run the column transformer, so you should be fitting on `X_train`, not `X_train_transformed`.

Comment: That gives me a different type of error: ```ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').```
Makes me think that the transformations didn't happen. Any thoughts on how to inspect that visually?

Comment: For that, provide the full error traceback.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. There is not enough space in comments. So I edited my original post.

Comment: The traceback confirms that it's the `LinearRegression` that's throwing the error.  Your preprocessor should indeed take care of any NaN, but an infinity or `value too large for dtype('float64')` are both still possible; try `np.isinf`, search for that error (there are many questions concerning it), or provide a data sample so someone here can help narrow it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with missing values. I checked your dataset : you have 10 missing values in your target variable ("life_expectancy"). You need to drop these lines : `df = df.dropna(subset=["Life expectancy"])`. Moreover, you have missing values in columns that you have not imputed (for instance "thinness 5-9 years"). With these modifications, it works fine on my computer.

Comment: Thanks! I totally overlooked the NaN values in the target variable.